# Skills in resume

Tags: resume, skills, employer

Should I mention in my resume (medical) I'll send to potential employer skills that I can't perform that well? Though before I'll get to work I'll take practical course and probably will improve myself in those skills.

Comment: Already having exposure to something is a huge plus. You don't have to say you're an expert, just say you have some experience or whatever is appropriate for your level of skill.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67452/how-honest-should-you-be-in-a-job-interview

Comment: Just make sure you don't overstate your skill level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be appropriate to just write about the skill you are good at. This would implicitly let your recruiter know about your skill set. Keep it focused.

Also if when I say I am not good at certain things, doesn't it implies, I am good at rest? This will make resume confusing and awkward.

If you are already pursuing some course to improve on some skills, you can mention about the courses, to let them know what you are heading towards.

During interview if asked, or in a situation, you can discuss your level and comfort with skills.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Never lie in a resume, but there's no reason to mention skills you don't have. I never mention the fact that I can't pilot an aeroplane, for example.

The resume is only there to get you an interview. At the interview, if they ask you about this particular skill, you can tell them about where you are with it.

Comment: Well,I said I am not that good, but did not say I can't perform them. I have done them but because of gap of practise  and lack of experience, at the beginning I might need time adopt to those skills.